# I have to click twice to update other table (Primefaces p:ajax)

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

i have a problem with primefaces 5.1 when i select a row from a table and i want to update other table i have to click twice to it works.

When i click a row in the tb_hojas table, this method cargarTablas() gets a data and updates the ArrayList from the tb_familia table , but i have to click twice the row of the tb_hojas table to see the new data in the tb_familia table.

In the bean when i use RequestScope it works but i need use ViewScoped.

This is my code XHTML:

```
    <h:form id="panel">

        <p:dataTable  id="tb_hojas" selection="#{hojaB2.filaHojas}" rowKey="#{lis.id}"
                      selectionMode="single" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300" resizableColumns="true" 
                      liveResize="true" var="lis" value="#{hojaB2.tablaHojas}"
                      paginator="true" rows="50" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                      rowsPerPageTemplate="25,30,50" filteredValue="#{hojaB2.filtroHojas}">
            <p:ajax  listener="#{hojaB2.cargarTablas()}" update=":panel" event="rowSelect" />  
            <p:column headerText="id" sortBy="#{lis.id}" filterBy="#{lis.id}">
                <h:outputText  value="#{lis.id}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="nombre" sortBy="#{lis.nombre}" filterBy="#{lis.nombre}">
                <h:outputText  value="#{lis.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
         <p:dataTable id="tb_familia" selection="#{hojaB2.filaFamilia}" selectionMode="single" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300" resizableColumns="true" 
                     liveResize="true" var="lis2" value="#{hojaB2.tablaFamilia}" rowKey="#{lis2.codigo}"
                     paginator="true" rows="50" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="25,30,50" filteredValue="#{hojaB2.filtroFamilia}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{hojaB2.cargarDialogoFamilia()}" oncomplete="PF('dlg_familia2').show();" update="@([id$=tb_familia]),@([id$=Form])" event="rowSelect" >  
            </p:ajax>
            <p:column headerText="codigo" sortBy="#{lis2.codigo}" filterBy="#{lis2.codigo}">
                <h:outputText  value="#{lis2.codigo}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="nombre" sortBy="#{lis2.nombre}" filterBy="#{lis2.nombre}">
                <h:outputText  value="#{lis2.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="cargo" sortBy="#{lis2.cargo}" filterBy="#{lis2.cargo}">
                <h:outputText  value="#{lis2.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: try adding `process="@form @this"` in your `<p:ajax>` where you are calling method `cargarTablas'

Comment: try setting <p:ajax global="false" />

Answer (score 0):

Why are you updating the very own form in which both `p:tables` reside?
I believe updating only the other table would fix you issue and enough for your requirement.

Example:

```
 <p:ajax  listener="#{hojaB2.cargarTablas()}" update="tb_familia" event="rowSelect" />
```